Excel vba - matrix formula does not calculate automatically
I am working on an Excel VBA routine that needs to execute the formula:
CHOOSECOLS(matrix, col_num1; col_num2). However, after the formula is written in the cell, at the end of the VBA routine, it is not calculated, displaying the error: #NAME. The syntax of the formula is not wrong, since when pressing the F2 + Enter keys, the formula is calculated and displays the expected value, but it is not calculated in any other way unless pressing the F2 + Enter keys. What should I do to correct this error and have the formula calculated automatically?
The code written is shown bellow:
Function DeterminarRangeTabela() As Range
    Dim wsBase As Worksheet
    Set wsBase = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1_BASE CARTEIRA")
    
    ' Determina a última linha e última coluna
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsBase.Cells(wsBase.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = wsBase.Cells(3, wsBase.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Determina o range da tabela a partir da linha 3 até a última linha e última coluna com dados
    Dim tblRange As Range
    Set tblRange = wsBase.Range(wsBase.Cells(4, 1), wsBase.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    
    ' Retorna o range da tabela
    Set DeterminarRangeTabela = tblRange
End Function



 Dim tblRange As Range
 Set tblRange = DeterminarRangeTabela()
 Dim wsCarteira As Worksheet
 Set wsCarteira = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2_CARTEIRA")
 Dim formula As String
    
 formula = "=CHOOSECOLS('1_BASE CARTEIRA'!" & tblRange.Address(False, False) & ",4,1,5,6,7,8,9,2,3,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,47,45,46,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57)"
 wsCarteira.Range("A5").Formula2 = formula 
 wsCarteira.Range("A5").Calculate




Out of curiosity, have you tried using .Formula2Local and ESCOLHERCOLS and ; instead of ,? Theoretically your current approach should work though.

Working OK for me (USA locale)

Please share the complete code. Try to replace wsCarteira.Range("A5").Calculate with wsCarteira.Calculate. If I use it, I don't get a Stale Error. Not sure if that's related. BTW, assuming there are an empty row and column to the bottom and the right respectively of your data, you could use my RefCurrentRegion function to reference your data range with Set tblRange = RefCurrentRegion(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1_BASE CARTEIRA").Range("A4")).

On another side note, If the header titles are the same in both sheets, you don't have to hard-code the column numbers. If you have referenced the source and destination header row ranges with shrg and dhrg respectively, you can use Dim sIndices() As Variant: sIndices = Application.Match(dhrg, shrg, 0) and use "," & Join(sIndices, ",") & ")" after the last &. Now you can move the destination columns at your pleasure. It is assumed that dhrg has as many or fewer cells as shrg.
